# JavaScript add .00 automatically in text box

Tags: javascript

I have 2 textboxes that add their value when `onchange` event is fired. The answer will be automatically shown on the third textbox which is `readonly`. But if the answer is a whole number or has a decimal of `.00` it just displays without `.00`.

This code is working on textbox that I can put a value:

```
function deduc3(obj) {
    var pagibig = document.getElementById('pagibig').value;
    obj.value = parseFloat(obj.value).toFixed(2);
    var deduc3 = parseFloat(pagibig)+parseFloat(document.getElementById('totaldeduc').value);
    if (!isNaN(deduc3)) {
        document.getElementById('totaldeduc').value = deduc3;
        netpay();
    }
}
```

But I can't make it work on `readonly` textbox.

Please help me to achieve this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `(0).toFixed(2) == "0.00"` - I don't get it?

Comment: For computing the two "0" decimal places are superfluous. You can force it by using `toFixed(2)` on output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `if` block:

```
document.getElementById('totaldeduc').value = deduc3.toFixed(2);
```

This will make the code look something like:

```
function deduc3(obj) {
    var pagibig = document.getElementById('pagibig').value;
    obj.value = parseFloat(obj.value).toFixed(2);
    var deduc3 = parseFloat(pagibig)+parseFloat(document.getElementById('totaldeduc').value);
    if (!isNaN(deduc3)) {
        document.getElementById('totaldeduc').value = deduc3.toFixed(2);
        netpay();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but it didn't work. I think the textbox `totaldeduc` would have its own function. I tried the function above but also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try with this code:

```
deduc3 = deduc3.toString().indexOf('.') > 0 ? deduc3 : deduc3 + '.00';
document.getElementById('totaldeduc').value = deduc3;
```